# How to render different mongodb schema/model in ejs and filter it

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, ejs

I am trying to filter out a collection that mongoDB finds and display it in a EJS file. However when I try to do this it would rather show me all the fields that are inside the collection rather then the one fields value that I want. The field that I want is called: "Silver" and  I am using nodejs, express and MongoDB.

This is the schema:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const merchant1schema = new mongoose.Schema({
 items: {
  type: Array
  },  
 silver: {
 type: Number
 }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('merchant1', merchant1schema);
```

This is the code I am using to find the collection and then display it back in EJS:

```js
router.get('/merchants', ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
merchant1.find({}, function (error, data) {
console.log(data)
 if (error) {
 console.log(error);
 } else {
res.render("merchants", {silver: data, user: req.user});
 }
})
})
```

However the data just shows the entire model when I console log it, instead of the field silver that I want. This is the output:
[ { items: [], _id: 60ec87b6051bf8edb62cf389, silver: 200000 } ]

I have tried to filter it out by doing for example: data.silver but this just returns an empty field. So I would like to know how I would be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I have found the solution. Apperently you just have to loop trough it in the ejs file:

```html
<% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
<h3 id="merchantsilvervalue"><%= data[i].silver%></h3>
<% } %>
```

This shows the value that i needed.